# MongoDB not recognising type Object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to figure why some array fields are returning type `object` when utilizing aggregate.
Assume a collection `baa`, whose field `foo` can have any of the following values `[]`, `[{...}]`, `[{...},{...}]` or `{...}`.

If I run the following query:

```
db.baa.aggregate([{$match:   { foo : {$type: "object"}} },
                  {$project: { foo : { $type: "$foo" }}}
                ]);
```

I get the following:

```
[{_id: xxx, foo: array}, ....]
```

This query would be later used to update all entries, whose `foo` fields is of type `object`.

Am I missing something in here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that the behavior changed in 3.6: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#querying-for-the-array-bson-type

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#arrays)

> For documents where field is an array, $type returns documents in which at least one array element matches a type passed to $type.

So the query `{foo: {$type: "object"}}` will match the document `{ foo: [{}]}` because the array contains an object.

You might try matching objects and explicitly excluding arrays:

```
{foo: {$type: "object", $not: {$type: "array" }}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 `$type` operators

- query operator, that matches if some type or its an array that contains at least 1 member with that type
  For example `{} ,[{}]` both match with "object"
  This returns true or false.
- aggregate operator that is strict and returns the exact type.
  For example {"$type" : "$foo"} will return "object" (a string with the type)

Your query has the problem that you use the query operator to do a strict type match.And also you are using the query operator in project, and you cant do that, in project you need the `$type` aggregate operator.

If you know that if its not array it will be object, you can use this.

```js
aggregate(
[ {
  "$match" : {
    "foo" : {
      "$not" : {
        "$type" : "array"
      }
    }
  }
} ]
)
```

We also have `$type` aggregate operator, that is more strict and will only match objects. (not also arrays that contain at least 1 object like the `$type` query operator)

```js
aggregate(
[ {
  "$match" : {
    "$expr" : {
      "$eq" : [ {
        "$type" : "$foo"
      }, "object" ]
    }
  }
} ]
)
```

With project i dont know what you want to do, but you cant use the query operator there. Only the aggregate operator.